# configuration to redirect from IP address to host name with APACHE

Tags: apache, hostname

I have configured the host name for a specific machine.

Ip Address : 192.XXX.XXX.XXX 
HostName : https://www.mymachine.com/link1

When the user hits the browser using IP, i want him to be redirected to hostname.

What is the apache configuration to be added?

Comment: what did you used tomcat or apache for that?

Comment: Im using apache for that

Answer (score 0):

first you try this short setting..

```
<VirtualHost *>
       ServerName www.myDomain.com
       DocumentRoot /www/myDomainRoot
</VirtualHost>
```

/* then after detailed configuration for that */

## /etc/apache2/sites-available/default

```
<VirtualHost <yourIP address>:<PortNo>>
    
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName application.mymachine #or whatever
    
DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```